# Is there any difference between ISO/IEC 13818-2 and H.262

Tags: mpeg, mpeg-2

I have read the H.262 document and a draft version of ISO/IEC 13818-2. I cannot figure out the difference between the two, can anyone point it out??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**ISO/IEC 13818-2** is identical to **ITU-T Rec. H.262**. The first two parts of MPEG-2 were developed in collaboration with ITU.

> In some areas of information technology which fall within ITU-T’s purview, the necessary standards are prepared on a
>   collaborative basis with ISO and IEC. The text of ITU-T Recommendation H.262 was approved on 10th of July 1995.
>   The identical text is also published as ISO/IEC International Standard 13818-2.

[Source](https://www.ic.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg121/Source-Coding_WS12/selected-readings/18_T-REC-H.262-199507-S__PDF-E.pdf)